# What brand is this vintage tripod?

Tags: tripod, equipment-identification

I have a tripod that is probably at least 30 years old and I would like to know the brand at least. It has a logo on it I have not been able to find nor interpret. Does it say GON? GOON? GOND? Something else entirely?
Below is a picture of the tripod and the logo on the dial thingy. It has no other markings I can find. It belonged to my Dad.

Edit to add: probably doesn't help, but it was either purchased in NZ post 1975 ish or the UK (England/Wales) prior to that.

[image: tipod]
[image: Logo on the dial thingy]
[image: leg of tripod]
[image: tripod top disassembled]

Comment: I hope you get an answer for this question. But I have to say... **thank you** for such a clear image of the logo. It really helps when trying to search for it.

Comment: I have no idea, but it's also very possible the logo is *just* a `G` with a weird stylized person holding a camera inside and not meant to represent letter forms. But then again, sure could be letters too!

Comment: Oh yeah! I thought it was an O, and N and a camera (which was maybe also a letter), but you're right, it is a person holding a camera! And then it could be both which would be extremely clever.

Comment: Are you able to remove the pan/tilt head from the top of the central column of the tripod? there may be a clue or more information on the fitting plate at the top of that column. I was wondering Gitzo but I've had a google for old Gitzo models and they show the full word 'gitzo' as the logo, eg in the 5th image on here: https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Tripode-GITZO-FRANCE-GILUX-REPORTER-RN-2-Tripod/253150947635

Comment: It doesn't seem to come apart at all - I tried undoing all the knobs and pulling stuff but nothing

Comment: Ok, it does come apart, but more importantly it is able to be put back together again, phew. No hidden symbols. You could hide a secret message in the hollow centre tube, but no one did.

Comment: Looks a bit like an OEM'd Linhof/Schiansky design to me....

Comment: I reached out to Gitzo's Contact Us, asking if the logo may have been a super early version for Gitzo, and they responded: "Good Afternoon Hueco, Thank you for reaching out to us regarding our Gitzo product. **The attached item is not a Gitzo product**. Additionally, we are unfamiliar with the logo so I am not sure who it may be. I am sorry I could not be more helpful. If you have any questions or require any additional assistance, please reach back out to us. Thank you Help Desk "

Comment: added two more photos, not sure if they're useful ones.

Comment: These two have the same legs with the rectangular shape and grooves, and same legs adjustment clasps, ,which I haven't seen on any other pictures I've looked at. https://www.etsy.com/listing/591296689/vintage-japanese-tripod-antique-tripod and https://www.worthpoint.com/worthopedia/vintage-camera-tripod-heavy-art-deco-455100151 some other parts like knobs also the same

Comment: With no answer for the Bounty it's goes to  and the ‍♀️‍♂️‍♀️‍♀️‍♂️.

Comment: Bonjour, Ce n'est absolument pas un Gitzo,il faut chercher une autre marque . bonne réception didier rob

Answer (score 2):

I found this tripod at my dad's house and was curious about its history when I found this topic. Mine is a little different from yours, but quite similar. It's made in Japan and the brand, as I can tell, is "Planet". I'm not a photographer so I don't have any knowledge about tripods, but as I can tell, this is a rugged one. Very stable and durable. Well, it is older than me (I was born in 1983). If you watch closely on mine there is something missing at the handle, and it is present on yours.

My dad bought here in Brazil in the late 70' - 80's, I believe.

[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]
[image: image 3]
[image: image 4]
[image: image 5]
[image: image 6]
[image: image 7]
[image: image 8]

Answer (score 1):

This is purely speculation, but perhaps the brand is "GOIN", Goin, or the like? Searching for "goin tripod uk", I came across several out-of-date Amazon.co.uk and eBay product links (unfortunately, without product images, hoping to find brand logos):

- [GOIN Q-470 PORTABLE Flexible Professional Aluminum Tripod &Ballhead](https://picclick.co.uk/Goin-Q-470-Portable-Flexible-Professional-Aluminum-Tripod-Ball-192353247445.html)
- [Goin Q-666C Professional Photography Carbon Tripod Monopod Kit & Ball Head Compact Travel](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Goin-Professional-Photography-Monopod-Compact/dp/B01N8UF4F1)
- etc. ...

Other advertised brands for "Q-666C Tripod" are Afaith, Zomei, Supon, QZSD (Quingzhangshedai), and others.

Based on the fairly recent existence of branded tripods being sold on Amazon.co.uk, I'm going to assume that Goin/GOIN was a photography accessories brand in the UK, that like many brands, was acquired at some point by a Chinese company in the last 20 years.

Comment: Best lead anyone has — although I kind of wonder if this is actually just _other_ random people trying to interpret that weird logo.

Comment: @mattdm No other random people than me. =)  I just thought perhaps "Goin" was maybe the brand, and searched for "Goin tripod", and tried to follow what I could. I wasn't able to find any other images of the logo anywhere else. The products in the links (hmm, outdated/defunct now) didn't have the logo in OQ. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯  =)

Answer (score 0):

Is it not a very old Velbon?  The leg sections and the clamps are reminiscent of early velbon tripods, and they were sold under various names and logos over the years. I have to admit that a search of older velbon tripod images did not however throw any light on the issue.

Comment: That'll be Velbon, not Velbron... not sure that's the right answer, but my first tripod was a Velbon Victory 450.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be a Gitzo tripod after all? I know that user [laurencemadill](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/24522/laurencemadill) already looked into that option, but the logo you posted in the question looks like a (creative) rendition of the logo of [Arséne Gitzhoven (the founder of Gitzo)](https://www.flickr.com/photos/heritagefutures/2991660784/sizes/z/), which is a `G` with an `A` in it (can't include the photo due to copyright).

You could even interpret that the logo actually spells out `Gitzo` as follows:

- The `G` is obvious
- The `I` is the white rectangle
- The `T` is rotated CCW by 90<sup>o</sup>. It is a combination of the white rectangle and the smaller black rectangle to the right of the white rectangle.
- The `Z` is rotated CCW by 90<sup>o</sup> and looks like an `N` in your photo
- The `O` is the black dot in the upper left inside the `G`.

Another thing that might point in that direction is the handle of the tripod-head arm. This seems to be a shutter release and looks similar to older [Gitzo's shutter releases](https://www.flickr.com/photos/heritagefutures/2980086863/sizes/l/).
Then again, I'm not an expert so perhaps all older shutter releases looked like that.

<sub>Source: http://camera-wiki.org/wiki/Gitzo</sub>

Comment: Additional source: http://camera-wiki.org/wiki/Gitzo_tripods - Which model for the win, I'll give you a upvote for now. Thanks. This was a *burning* question until it was forgotten.

Comment: All the Gitzo tripods I could find have round legs. The legs cross-section and lock mechanism looks more like the on found in Heiwa tripods. But I agree that the built-in release hints at Gitzo. Tripod and head could be from separate manufacturers.

Comment: @xenoid, yes that's the issue I'm running into as well. All the Gitzo tripods seem to have some markings on the tripod, this one doesn't. So the separate head/tripod theory is likely. Unfortunately there are no more photos of the tripod or head, so unless the question asker returns, this is probably a dead end.

Comment: Gitzo is a stretch because too many letters need to be read sideways.

Comment: Agree. But to make it work as word "Gitzo", a symbol "someone taking a picture" *and* refer to the inital logo I thought one needs to make compromises as a designer, so perhaps plausible? Maybe as some sort of special edition?

Comment: @Rob I reached out to Gitzo's Contact Us, asking if the logo may have been a super early version for Gitzo, and they responded: "Good Afternoon Hueco, Thank you for reaching out to us regarding our Gitzo product. **The attached item is not a Gitzo product**. Additionally, we are unfamiliar with the logo so I am not sure who it may be. I am sorry I could not be more helpful. If you have any questions or require any additional assistance, please reach back out to us. Thank you Help Desk "